# How to remove duplicate in Left Join query result

Tags: sql, postgresql

Take a look at these tables:

**Table hirings:**

[image]

**Table skill_hiring:**

[image]

I want to show skills related to hiring. As you can see, there are 3 records in table `skill_hirings` that `hiring_id = 3`. So when I use the left join query, it is returning 3 same records.

So I want to remove the duplication record, and returning only the unique record by `id_hiring`.

I read some StackOverflow QnA, they suggest using the `GROUP BY` clause but I still can't figure it out.

**The query:**

```
SELECT id_hiring, company_id, title, status, start_salary, end_salary, 
viewer, open, close, expired 
 FROM (
    SELECT h.id id_hiring, * FROM hirings h 
    LEFT JOIN skill_hirings sh ON sh.hiring_id = h.id 
    LEFT JOIN skills s ON s.id = sh.skill_id 
    WHERE title ILIKE '%'
) RESULT
```

**Query and the result:**

[image]

**Note:** The wildcard `%` in the query will replace with variable

Comment: what output you are expecting?

Comment: Your question is totally baffling.  The `LEFT JOIN` is doing exactly what it is supposed to be doing.  Perhaps you should explain what you *want* to happen.

Comment: If you are expecting skills for a particular hiring id, shouldn't it be inner join? Again, I am saying this based on the information you have provided on the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I fixed the question, please check it again

Comment: I'm also not sure what result you want. Could you show the results you want, please? You don't seem to be using anything from the skills table, do you need to join with it? It also seems like you don't need the subquery, you could use [column aliases](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) instead.

Comment: It's not entirely clear where your fields in your query are coming from as you've used the `SELECT *` mechanism in the subquery and not listed all the fields with a table alias (only the first one, `h.id`). The table `hiring_skill` doesn't show duplicates. It shows that the hiring record with `id=13` is associated with three different skills. If you don't care what skills are associated as calling them duplicates would suggest, then like @Schwern, I don't think you need the subquery.

Comment: @AlifRamdani please provide a few data samples as text (**never post code or data as images**). Preferably add `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements to your question. This will significantly improve your chances to get a decent answer ;) cheers

Comment: @Schwern I think I already make it clear that I want to remove the duplication of the left join query result above. I want to show the skills required in certain 'hiring'. So I need to left join `hiring_skills` table to the `hirings` table. Sorry for the late response, I hope you still have time for my question

Comment: @SteveLovell there is actually a list of id (ex: city_id, company_id, etc) on that `SELECT` query. It is needed to perform some `LEFT JOIN` queries to other related tables. Based on your answer, I probably wrong to use `LEFT JOIN` in this case, can you suggest what query that proper to achieve my goal? Sorry for the late response, I hope you still have time for my question, thank you

Comment: I would like to help, but what you want remains unclear. How do you want to show the list of skills for a hiring in a single row? Do you want just the skill names, or something more? You have to tell us what you want so we can help. Please show us your desired results, it would help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

At the point of writing this answer we are still in the dark as to which fields come from which tables. Based on current explanation, it isn't clear why the following wouldn't work for your needs (though it may not run at all depending upon whether any of the required fields really come from the `skill_hirings` or `skills table` which I have not included).

```
SELECT
    h.id as id_hiring,
    h.company_id,
    h.title,
    h.status,
    h.start_salary,
    h.end_salary, 
    h.viewer,
    h.open,
    h.close,
    h.expired 
FROM
    hirings h 
WHERE
    h.title ILIKE '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick 'n dirty solution would be do the same query twice and put them together with `UNION`. It removes duplicate lines.

Probably not the most optimized solution, but should work.